# stopping execution in netbeans doesn't stop jvm (under mac osx)

Tags: java, macos, netbeans

I'm used to run (for testing purposed) java applications from IDE. Start, verify, stop execution in output window in Netbeans. This works flawlessly under linux and windows but under mac osx for reasons beyond me the despite execution being stopped (red stop button greyed out, etc.) the java process persists in the background.
It this some inherent property of mac osx? (most of the applications stay running but I would assume that when I stop java from IDE it should basically kill it)

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in NetBeans way of launching apps - https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=232322