# Endpoint not stopped under netbeans and mac os, while working under windows

Tags: java, soap, netbeans, jax-ws

I am following a tutorial for building soap ws, and I can't understand why Netbeans does not stop the endpoint, namely the java application, thus letting it using the port.

I run the following code, under MAC os using Netbeans (with jdk 1.7.25)

```
public class HelloPublisher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String localhost =InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
            //InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress().getHostAddress();
            System.out.println(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
            String port = "5901";
            String url = "http://" + localhost + ":" + port + "/";
            System.out.println(url);
            Endpoint e = Endpoint.publish(url+ "ws/hello", new HelloWorldImpl());
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            System.out.println("errore");
        }

    }
}
```

But when I stop it and then run it again I obtain the following error: address already in use.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.ServerRtException: Server Runtime Error: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.ServerMgr.createContext(ServerMgr.java:102)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.HttpEndpoint.publish(HttpEndpoint.java:63)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:171)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createAndPublishEndpoint(ProviderImpl.java:113)
    at javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish(Endpoint.java:240)
    at it.unitn.lsde.firstsoap.endpoint.HelloPublisher.main(HelloPublisher.java:29)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl.<init>(ServerImpl.java:100)
    at sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerImpl.<init>(HttpServerImpl.java:50)
    at sun.net.httpserver.DefaultHttpServerProvider.createHttpServer(DefaultHttpServerProvider.java:35)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer.create(HttpServer.java:129)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.ServerMgr.createContext(ServerMgr.java:84)
    ... 5 more
```

This is due to the fact that the java application is still running when I press stop button under Netbeans, and I have to close it manually if I want to reuse the same address or I have to change the port. I expect it to close it but it doesn't happen.

So question is: is Netbeans doing something wrong? or am I using the endpoint in the wrong way?
I don't want to change every time the port.. the same code works perfectly in windows..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, killing the application that occupied a port should release that port for future bindings. However, you can always ensure to stop the service you have published:

```
Endpoint ep = Endpoint.create(new HelloWorldImpl());
ep.publish("http://" + localhost + ":" + port + "/ws/hello");
..
//DETECT STOP SIGNAL
ep.stop();
```

Stop signal can be some flag that you can set through a servlet, for example. This flag should be checked in regular intervals or in the loop.

Comment: Thanks for answering, and giving the hint. I'm also aware of what you say, in fact the same code works under windows and it release the occupied port, without checking the stop/kill signal. I expect the same behavior under Mac Os. If I can not find the solution I will try to work it out with your suggestion :D maybe is a problem of netbeans but the other application are closed without any problem.. :\

Comment: @LMG You are welcome. Yes, it should definitely release a port when killed (killed=stop button pressed), maybe it is some weird bug in Mac Os version of Netbeans (check if it is really killed!). If you don't succeed, try with stop signal that I have suggested, that should do the trick.

Comment: I checked yesterday before posting, and I had a bunch of java process running which were not closed.. It seems that some java application are closed, and some others are not.. :(

Comment: ehy man thanks for interesting, unfortunatly I didn't. It seems is a problem of netbeans, and this makes me a bit disappointed (looks like under eclipse is working), and if I run the sotware by command line everything is killed when I kill the process with ctrl-c, so I didn't find a "real" solution for netbeans. Your workaround should work but does not fix netbeans bug. :\

Comment: @LMG If you have some free time, report this problem to Netbeans team, they are really quick in resolving bugs. Of course, fixing Netbeans bug is out of scope for one plain Stackoverflow answer like mine ;) Regards!

Comment: I just came here having similar problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566583/stopping-execution-in-netbeans-doesnt-stop-jvm-under-mac-osx - I think it's the same - basically Netbeans doesn't kill/stop jvm when stopping app from IDE. Anyhow - was it already reported?

Comment: It seems like a NetBeans way of launching apps bug - https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=232322

Comment: @Woytek Thanks for the link, we can now track the resolving process.